# Run different length arrays in one function

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino-uno

I want to make a buzzer on my Arduino play different songs one after the other. I have put notes in arrays to make up the songs and a function to call the different arrays. My problem is that the arrays has different lengths which results in the songs being cut when I play them. I have defined the length in the "int arrSize" and made it to the length of the array called MikkelRev_melody, but the longer songs is then cut of. Does anyone know of a good way to solve this?

here is my code:

```
int buzzer = 13;
int tempo = 120; //melodiens tempo i bpm

//Defining the needed notes 
#define T_C 262
#define T_D 294
#define T_E 330
#define T_F 349
#define T_G 392
#define T_A 440
#define T_Ab 466
#define T_B 493
#define T_C2 523
#define T_D2 587

//arrays with notes
int AlleFugler_melody[] = {T_C, T_E, T_G, T_C2, T_A, T_C2, T_A, 
                T_G, T_F, T_G, T_E, T_C, T_D, T_C};

int MikkelRev_melody[] = {T_E, T_G, T_C, T_E, T_G, T_C, T_F, 
                   T_A, T_C2, T_A, T_A, T_G};

int LisaGikkTilSkolen_melody[] = {T_C, T_D, T_E, T_F, T_G, T_G, T_A, T_A, T_A, T_A, 
               T_G, T_F, T_F, T_F, T_F, T_E, T_E, T_D, T_D, T_D, T_D, T_C};

int LilleMaltrost_melody[] = {T_E, T_F, T_G, T_G, T_E, T_F, T_G, T_G, 
               T_A, T_G, T_F, T_F, T_E, T_D};

int BjornenSover_melody[] = {T_C, T_C, T_C, T_E, T_D, T_D, 
                T_D, T_F, T_E, T_E, T_D, T_D, T_C};

int BamsesFodselsdag_melody[] = {T_C2, T_D2, T_C2, T_D2, T_C2, T_D2, 
                T_C2, T_D2, T_C2, T_Ab, T_G, T_E, T_F};

//duration of each note
int AlleFugler_durations[] = {2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2};

int MikkelRev_durations[] = {4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2};

int LisaGikkTilSkolen_durations[] = {4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2};

int LilleMaltrost_durations[] = {6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2};

int BjornenSover_durations[] = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2};

int BamsesFodselsdag_durations[] = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2};


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  PlaySong(LisaGikkTilSkolen_melody, LisaGikkTilSkolen_durations, tempo);
  PlaySong(MikkelRev_melody, MikkelRev_durations, tempo);
  PlaySong(AlleFugler_melody, AlleFugler_durations, tempo);
  PlaySong(LilleMaltrost_melody, LilleMaltrost_durations, tempo);
  PlaySong(BjornenSover_melody, BjornenSover_durations, tempo);
  PlaySong(BamsesFodselsdag_melody, BamsesFodselsdag_durations, tempo);
}

void loop() 
{
}

void PlaySong(int notes[], int durations[], int BPM)
{ 
  int arrSize = sizeof(MikkelRev_melody)/sizeof(int); //leanght of array playing
  
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < arrSize; thisNote++) 
  {
    int noteDuration = (int)((750 * (120 * 2 / BPM)) / durations[thisNote] + 0.); //defining duration of tone
    tone(buzzer, notes[thisNote], noteDuration);

    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.20; //defining pause between tones
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes); //leanght of tone
    noTone(buzzer); //add pause between tones 
  }
  delay(1000); //one second pause before next song
}
```

Comment: use vector instead of raw array

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. I would do it like C string. Define one more note with value 0 or -1 and put it at the end of each array. Then iterate array until you reach that value.